# How to localize picker "Ok" button in MAUI

Tags: android, ios, localization, maui, picker

I have a MAUI application which support android and iOS platform. We need to localize the picker "OK" and "Cancel" button. How to do this in MAUI. I did the same in Xamarin using Effects, but when I tried the same on MAUI it's not working,
please help me.

```
public class PickerDoneButtonEffect : Picker
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty DoneButtonTextProperty =
          BindableProperty.CreateAttached("DoneButtonText",
                                          typeof(string),
                                          typeof(PickerDoneButtonEffect),
                                          string.Empty,
                                          propertyChanged: OnDoneButtonPropertyPropertyChanged);
    public string DoneButtonText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(DoneButtonTextProperty); }
        set => SetValue(DoneButtonTextProperty, value);
    }


    public static string GetDoneButtonText(BindableObject element)
    {
        return (string)element.GetValue(DoneButtonTextProperty);
    }

     public static void SetTintColor(BindableObject element, string value)
    {
        element.SetValue(DoneButtonTextProperty, value);
    }


    static void OnDoneButtonPropertyPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        AttachEffect(bindable as View, $"{newValue}");
    }


    static void AttachEffect(View element, string buttonText)
    {
        var effect = element.Effects.FirstOrDefault(x => x is PickerDoneButton) as PickerDoneButton;

         if (effect != null)
        {
            element.Effects.Remove(effect);
        }

        element.Effects.Add(new PickerDoneButton(buttonText));
    }


    public class PickerDoneButton : RoutingEffect
    {
        public string ButtonTitle { get; set; }

         public PickerDoneButton(string buttonTitle) : base($"MyCompany.{nameof(PickerDoneButton)}")
        {
            ButtonTitle = buttonTitle;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the effect implementation for android.

```
public class PickerLocalization : PlatformEffect
{
    AlertDialog _dialog;
    PickerDoneButtonEffect.PickerDoneButton _effect;

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        _effect = (PickerDoneButton)Element.Effects.FirstOrDefault(e => e is PickerDoneButton);

         if (_effect != null && Control != null && Element is Picker)
        {
            Control.Click += ShowDialog; 

        }
    }

     private void ShowDialog(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var model = Element as Picker;
        if (_dialog == null && model != null)
        {
            using (var builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.Platform.CurrentActivity))
            {
                if (!model.IsSet(Picker.TitleColorProperty))
                {
                    builder.SetTitle(model.Title ?? "");
                }
                else
                {
                    var title = new SpannableString(model.Title ?? "");
                    title.SetSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(model.TitleColor.ToAndroid()), 0, title.Length(), SpanTypes.ExclusiveExclusive);

                    builder.SetTitle(title);
                } 

                string[] items = model.Items.ToArray();
                builder.SetItems(items, (s, e) => ((IElementController)model).SetValueFromRenderer(Picker.SelectedIndexProperty, e.Which));

                builder.SetNegativeButton(_effect.ButtonTitle, (o, args) => { });

                ((IElementController)model).SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedPropertyKey, true);

                _dialog = builder.Create();
            }
            _dialog.SetCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
            _dialog.DismissEvent += (sender, args) =>
            {
                (model as IElementController)?.SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedPropertyKey, false);
                _dialog?.Dispose();
                _dialog = null;
            };
            _dialog.Show();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnDetached()
    {
        Control.Click -= ShowDialog;
    }
}
```

Here is the effect implementation for iOS

```
 public class PickerLocalization : PlatformEffect
{
    UIButton _doneBtn;
    UIBarButtonItem _originalDoneBarButtonItem;

     protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        var effect = (PickerDoneButton)Element.Effects.FirstOrDefault(e => e is PickerDoneButton);

         if (effect != null && Control?.InputAccessoryView is UIToolbar toolbar && toolbar.Items?.Count() > 0)
        {
            _originalDoneBarButtonItem = toolbar.Items[1];
            _doneBtn = new UIButton(UIButtonType.System);
            _doneBtn.SetTitle(effect.ButtonTitle, UIControlState.Normal);
            _doneBtn.TitleLabel.Font = UIFont.BoldSystemFontOfSize(UIFont.SystemFontSize);
            _doneBtn.TouchUpInside += HandleButtonClicked;

             _originalDoneBarButtonItem.CustomView = _doneBtn;
        }
    }

      protected override void OnDetached()
    {
        if (_doneBtn != null)
        {
            _doneBtn.TouchUpInside -= HandleButtonClicked;
            _doneBtn = null;
            _originalDoneBarButtonItem.CustomView = null;
        }
    }

     void HandleButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UIApplication.SharedApplication.SendAction(_originalDoneBarButtonItem.Action, _originalDoneBarButtonItem.Target, sender: null, forEvent: null);
    }
}
```

And configure the effects in MauiProgram.cs file.

Comment: What does the not work mean? Did you use the Custom Renderers in .NET MAUI by following [this artial](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/Using-Custom-Renderers-in-.NET-MAUI)?

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT,  localization is not working for Picker Done and OK button.

Comment: Did you try to convert the custom renderer to the custom handler?

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT, I'm not using custom renderer ,used effect for the localization.